Facet Grid scales
Lets assume we have the following df
df <- data.frame(result = c(runif(50, min = 1, max = 2),
                            runif(50, min = 10, max = 20),
                            runif(50, min = 100, max = 300)),
                 material = rep(c("M1", "M2", "M3"), each = 50),
                 lot = rep(c("Lot1", "Lot2", "Lot3"), times = 50))

And using ggplot2 library we are creating the following plot:
ggplot(df, aes(x=lot, y=result, fill =  lot)) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(color= lot), alpha = 0.5, size = 3, na.rm = T)+ 
  geom_boxplot(aes(color= lot), alpha = 0.2, size = 0.3, na.rm = T)+
  facet_grid(rows = vars(material), scales = "free")+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("Result")+ 
  theme_bw()

What I would like to do is to change on purpose the y-axis scale ranges to a prespecified range.
y_limits <- list(
"M1" = c(0.8, 2.2),
"M2" = c(8, 22),
"M3" = c(80, 320)
)

Is there any possible way to do that?
I could not find anything on the internet to do this!
